# Javascript parseFloat() change number

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a strange problem with `JavaScript` .
I have text value in a `textbox` '25000000' when i am
using `parsefloat(txt.value)`, the returned value is 25000 !??

Why is 25000000 changed to 25000 ?

Comment: Is it definitely all zeros?  If there was an O hidden in there instead for instance, the `parseFloat` would stop at that point and return just what had been parsed so far.  Other than that, there's not really enough information in your question to give you an answer.

Comment: txt.value from  input?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all Responses.
The problem was for ',' in price.
Of course we replace ',' with '' ,but replace method
only change first one like "25,000,000,000"=>"25000,000,000".
I used `str.split(',').join('')` and problem solve and parsefloat returned correctly.
regards
ali

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an alphabet somewhere in your numbers. Check the example below.There is an error in your code.

```
parseFloat(" 250000000 ") = 250000000
parseFloat("2018@geeksforgeeks") = 2018
parseFloat("geeksforgeeks@2018") = NaN
```